# Custom loss in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I'd like to implement a custom loss in Keras that takes the last affine layer as an input. This is the SGM loss described in [Hariharan et al. 2017](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.02819.pdf)

This means that the loss function doesn't get only y_true and y_predict as parameters, but also the last affine layer. How can this be implemented in keras?

Comment: It is useful to post what you have at the moment, this will also entice people to help more!

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom layer and call `self.add_loss` in the `call` method. The value should be a scalar tensor averaged across the samples in the batch. This will then be added to the usual loss function (the one that is a function of `y_true` and `y_pred`) when you compile the model. If this is not required, you also have the option of specifying `loss=None`.

See for example https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/variational_autoencoder.py where the KL divergence is added to the Bernoulli negative log-likelihood to form the negative evidence lower bound loss for the variational autoencoder.